# runescape private server calling a method from another class

Tags: java, command

Okay, so I want it so if player typs ::help, the method from RequestHelp.java will run,

Command`if (playerCommand.startsWith("help") && (c.playerRights >= 0)) {
c.sendMessage("A staff member has been contacted, please wait.");
(right here is where I want the method from the other class to run'
}`

this is the method from RequestHelp.java

```
    public static void callForHelp(Client c) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - c.lastRequest < 30000) {
        c.sendMessage("It has only been "+ getTimeLeft(c) +" seconds since your last request for help!");
        c.sendMessage("Please only request help from the staff every 30 seconds!");
        if (!requestingHelp) {
            c.setSidebarInterface(3, 3213);
            c.getPA().sendFrame106(3);
        }
        return;
    }
    requestingHelp = true;
    otherPlayer = c.playerName;
    c.lastRequest = System.currentTimeMillis();
    setInterface(c);
    PlayerHandler.messageAllStaff(Misc.optimizeText(getPlayer().playerName) +" needs help, their cords are: "+ playerCoords() +".", true);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestHelp helper = new RequestHelp();
if(playerCommand.equals("::help")) {
    helper.callForHelp(client);
}
```

This should work.